# Base class data member type depends on derived class

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding polymorphism in c++:

header file

```
class Base {
public:
  type1 data;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
  type2 data;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
  type3 data;
};
```

code:

```
Base * obj;

if (...)
  obj = new Derived1();
else
  obj = new Dervied2();

// Do something on declared object
DoSomething( obj->data );
```

What should I put as type1 in base class if the type depends on the derived class being defined? The function DoSomething() will be overloaded to take in either type2 or type3.

Comment: If you need to change the base class in a way that depends on a derived class, then you're using inheritance incorrectly.   A solution that often works well, if your design is sound, is to provide an empty polymorphic base class, and have the derived classes specialise operations and take care of ALL their data requirements.

Comment: You don't mix run-time and compile-time (overloading) polymorphism like this. What is the relation between `type1-3`? Can **that** be expressed by inheritance?

Comment: `Derived1::data` and `Derived2::data` have nothing to do with `Base::data`.  Derived class data does not override or replace base class data, they exist independently. You can only access base data via a base pointer.

Comment: _@nasw_264_ To make base classes depend on their derived classes traits, the usual pattern to go with is the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Deciding at runtime what to use would be restricted in some ways though. You would need to introduce another layer of indirection, e.g. introducing a pure `virtual` `BaseBase` class and access `data` through a virtual function.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I understand now that my current implementation might be wrong/not ideal. I'm new to c++ but you guys have given me some good alternatives to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the only (*) right incantation.

```
class Base {
  public:
     virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
     // no data
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
  public:
     void DoSomething() override;
  private:
      type2 data;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
  public:
     void DoSomething() override;
  private:
      type3 data;
};

Base * obj;

if (...)
  obj = new Derived1();
else
  obj = new Derived2();

obj->DoSomething();
```

(*) There are other *valid* (as in "it compiles at runs") ways but they are not *right*.

Comment: How can I access the "data" variable through obj since it is not declared in base class?

Comment: @nasw_264 You cannot, you should not, and you do not need to. **All** access to data is within DoSomething or other virtual functions. That's the **whole** point.

Comment: What if I need to pass the data to another class?

Comment: Clients of Base do not see the data, do not know about the data, do not care about the data. They call a virtual function that does what needs to be done. That's it. If **the virtual function** needs to pass the data further, it just does it. **That's the whole point**. Let it sink.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however obviously I'm still missing something. Is it considered bad practice to access class variable directly?

Comment: Try getting a book on object oriented programming. Your last question isn't very clear. What an example of good (indirect?) access to a class variable would be, in your opinion? In OOP *public data* is considered bad practice.